# NSURLSession restart the request

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession

I am using the `NSURLsession` for network calls. I need to store the details to perform the restart on network error or manually when user performs the sync from app.

Do I need to store the `NSURLsession` object or `NSURLSessionDataTask` or `taskIdentifier` to achieve this?

I need to initiate the restart from some other class.

Help appreciated

Comment: How about just saving the url as string somewhere?

Comment: Then need to save the urlstring, request headers, params and authentication details.

Comment: Then, store the `NSURLRequest` object, it's copyable and archivable.

Comment: You mean to perform the restart to store the `NSURLRequest` object and create a object of `NSURLSession` using the urlRequest

Comment: I mean, store the configured `NSURLRequest` object with all params headers and all you have mentioned above before starting url session task, and if task failed, use that object to make new connection.

Comment: I need to initiate the request from the view controller and that will be decided by the user when he wants to perform the sync for cancelled or failed requests. If it is retry I got this will work fine but here its about restarting the cancelled requests.

Answer (score -2):

NSURLSession is the task, an instance of NSURLSessionTask. Three type

```
data tasks
upload tasks
download tasks.
```

You can **cancel** , **resume** these task at any point if your session still validate. If your session invalidate, You need to call that code again which start this flow.

You can see here [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html)